# Can you catch Dart errors of a specific type WITH specific parameter values?

Tags: dart, error-handling

I have an app that uses Firestore to get data, and I created a custom exception type, "NoFirestoreDataException" that I can throw when I don't get any data back in a case where I'd expect to.

The exception type has one parameter, `dataType,` which takes a value from an enumeration of all the data types I'm using in Firestore, and the return message just basically says no data of `dataType` was found in this query.

I have some places where I specifically catch this type of error, but I'd like to shrink that down so I can just catch it if the data type matches what I'm actually expecting.

If I'm searching for a `User` and I get a `NoFirestoreDataException(FirestoreDataType.Goal)` back, I don't want to handle that error as gracefully, as this would be highly unexpected.

Is there a way to do this with a single custom exception type?

Comment: `catch` operates only on the object's type.  If you need more granularity, your exception handler will need to check the properties of the caught object and `rethrow` it if you don't want to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @jamesdlin's comment, I either need to:

- create separate types of exceptions for each of these cases, or:
- Have one type of exception, catch that type, but then add an `if` statement to make sure that the property inside the exception matches what I'd expect it to do.